# Why does my code not give a proper output?

Tags: c

This is the code to print all armstrong numbers within a range m to n as input by the user. But when i run it, it does not give proper output. Suppose i input m as 1 and n as some 10000, it only shows '1 is armstrong' and nothing else.Please tell me if something is wrong in my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{

    int m,n,a,i,j=0,r; 
    printf("Enter m\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);

    printf("Enter n\n");

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=m;i<=n;i++)
    {
        int temp=i;
        while(i>0)
        {
            r=i%10;
            j=j+r*r*r;
            i=i/10;
        }

        if(j==temp)
        {
            printf("%d is armstrong\n",temp);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Try moving an if statement into the while loop.

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to modify `i` both in the for loop (`i++`) and also in the while loop (`i=i/10;`).  It means your for-loop will not run across all values from `m` to `n`.

Answer (score 2):

I see two faults in your program, `j` is only initialised once, and you are destroying the loop control `i`. To remedy, initialise `j` inside the loop, and work with `temp` instead of with `i`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)                      // modern style
{
    int m, n, i, j, r; 
    printf("Enter m\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    printf("Enter n\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i = m; i <= n; i++) {
        j = 0;                      // initialise j
        int temp = i;
        while(temp > 0) {           // work with temp
            r = temp % 10;
            j = j + r * r * r;
            temp = temp / 10;
        }

        if(j == i) {
            printf("%d is armstrong\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
Enter m
1
Enter n
10000
1 is armstrong
153 is armstrong
370 is armstrong
371 is armstrong
407 is armstrong
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i=m; i<=n; i++)
{
    j = 0;
    int temp = i;
    while(temp > 0)
    {
        r = temp % 10;
        j = j + r*r*r;
        temp = temp/10;
    }

    if(j == i)
    {
        printf("%d is armstrong\n", i);
    }


}
```

In while loop you need to work with variable temp to leave i intact so the for loop continues correctly. Before starting new while loop set j = 0 to start counting again from 0. In if statement compare j == i because temp variable is reduced to 0 by while loop.